# How to delete rows that have valid referencing keys in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, delete-row

I have two tables in my database named `user` and `account`. The `user` table has a foreign key column named `account_id` which is bound to the `id` column of table `account`.

More specifically, the simplified database structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE "user" (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            login VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            pass VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            account_id INTEGER  NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT account_fk FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
      REFERENCES account (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE NOT DEFERRABLE
);
```

I'd like to know whether it is possible to delete a row of table `user` without also deleting the `account` being referenced by the specific record?

Whenever I try to delete an `account`, the related rows in table `user` are deleted as well (due to the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause). However, I need the same series of events taking place in the other direction as well.

Comment: What should happen if two or more users refer to _the same_ account.id ?

Comment: I have one-to-one relation.

Comment: If you really have a one-to-one relation, you could combine the two tables into one. No additional logic needed!

Comment: Probably this is the easiest way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use trigger for that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_account() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM account WHERE id = OLD.account_id;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_delete_account
  AFTER DELETE ON "user"
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_account();
```

But keep in mind that other users referencing the same account will be also deleted. You probably have one-to-one relation and need unique key on user.account_id to enforce that.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But our DB was changed so question became not actual :) But I will keep it in my mind!